# How do I set up Vue 3 + Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, frontend

I would like to use Vue 3 components/vue files within Blade Templates. I have been spending the whole day trying to get it working, so this is my last hope.I tried watching video tutorials, I tried reading the documentation, I have tried pretty much everything.

I first tried to install Vue using npm: `npm install vue` but I was told that wasn't enought; I had to use the Vue CLI in order to use components/.vue files as the CLI ships with all compilers and webpack configurations.

That's what I did:

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

But it didn't work, it gave me an error:

> Vue command not found

So I tried using `npx`:

`npx @vue/cli create myApp`

That worked but it starts the server like a separated application, on a different url other than my Laravel app. I know that's the expected behavior and that's why I have been spending the whole day trying to find a solution.

I also tried laravel/ui but it doesn't seem to work in Laravel 8.

I tried to manually set up my Laravel+ Vue app but didn't work either:

> mix.js('resources/assets/js/main.js', 'public/js');

Inside my `main.js` file

```
<script>
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from "./components/App.vue"
createApp(App).mount("#app");
</script>
```

It says that Vue could not be resolved.

**My question is:**

How do I use/call Vue components in my Blade Template? Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: There is a [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-vue-3/episodes/14) describing how to do this

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple options to integrate Vue with Laravel.

**Option 1: Vue CLI**
Using VueCLI you will install a whole new Vue project (separated from Laravel proejct) that works better independently as a front end, and talks to your backend through something like an HTTP API made with Laravel.

---

**Option 2: Laravel 8 Breeze + Inertia**
Breeze is the new UI package for Laravel 8 that uses Tailwind CSS. Inertia.js is a package to use Laravel server-side routing and controllers.

For installation run in your new Laravel project run:

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

php artisan breeze:install --inertia

npm install

npm run dev

php artisan migrate
```

Please refer to the Laravel docs about installation of these packages: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation

---

**Option 3: Laravel UI**
This package is still supported by Laravel 8. If you have a fresh installation of Laravel, just run:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then run:

```
// Basic scaffolding
php artisan ui vue

// login / registration scaffolding
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Please refer to the documentation in the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/laravel/ui

Comment: Yes thank you. I'm familiarised with the method one. I mean, that would certainly work using HTTP requests haha and probably would be easier to, but I would like to find a way to actually integrate components with my Laravel app without having to exclusively use Vue as a whole separated app, like hust the frontend itself. I, however, appreciate your clarifications. Actually it's not a fresh installation of Laravel , I upgraded it from version 7 to 8 by the way. It's giving me a couple of errors when I run the command `composer require laravel/ui`

Comment: Option 2 worked the best for me. It adds the basic auth scaffold + setup the app with clean Vue3 frontend. One line of code and you are ready to go with Laravel + Vue3

Comment: I installed Breeze without inertia and in that case, Vue was not installed. For anyone who doesn't want to use Inertia but still wants Breeze to deal with the Auth UI and auth web routing, you will need to install Vue separately. E.g. add `.vue()` to the webpack.mix.js, and install `vue` and `vue-loader` packages. Some Vue packages that you are using may need jQuery to run. As Lavavel 8 does not use Bootstrap nor jQuery by default, you will also need to add `window.$ = require('jquery');` and `window.JQuery = require('jquery');` to your `bootstrap.js`. Hope this helps someone save hours.

Comment: option 3 does not give you vue 3